# The viewset didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, django-templates

I am returning `TemplateResponse` from `viewset` like this:

```
return TemplateResponse(request, 'payments/cybersource_stampduty.html', template_data)
```

but I am getting error:

> The view payments.views.CyberSourceResponseViewSet didn't return an
>   HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Why am I getting this error?

incase if someone want to see entire function, here is how it looks like

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    transaction = CyberSourceTransaction.objects.filter(
        uuid=request.data['req_transaction_uuid']).first()

    # if its a stampduty
    if transaction.selected_plan_name == 'stampduty':
      template_data = {
        'consumer': transaction.transfer_to,
        'decision': request.data['decision'],
        'transaction_uuid': request.data['req_transaction_uuid'],
        'reference_number': transaction.reference_number,
        'amount': transaction.amount,
        'currency': transaction.currency,
        'wukla_url': settings.WUKLA_URL,
        'paksign_url': settings.PAKSIGN_URL,
        'subscription_url': settings.DOMAIN
      }
      logger.info("Handling Cybersource transaction response with transaction_uuid: "
                + request.data['req_transaction_uuid'], extra={'user': ''})
      return TemplateResponse \
        (request, 'payments/cybersource_stampduty.html', template_data)
```

Comment: Normally it means that there is a code path that does not return anything. Can you share the entire function?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have updated my question. You can have a look at entire function

Comment: your `return` statement into `if` block and seems this line is not executed at all

Comment: @ZohabAli: what if `if transaction.selected_plan_name == 'stampduty':` does not hold? Right now yo did not define an `else` casse.

Comment: @MikhailTokarev I have double checked it by using `pdb.set_trace()` and I can confirm that it is being executed

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that's a different case i 'll handle it but right now this one is not working for me